# How to change primary key in AspNetUserRole in identity, and implement one primarykey

Tags: foreign-keys, asp.net-identity, primary-key, identity, user-roles

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
}

public class IdentityUserRole<TKey> where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{   
    public virtual TKey UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual TKey RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to extract `userId` and `RoleId` from primary key, and implement as foreign key, import primary key `Id`

No matter what I searched, I did not find a solution